# Strategy for stream analytics for Data on mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, architecture, analytics, spark-streaming

I am quite new to the world of Big Data and after hours of readings and documentation, I decided to seek your advice. Here's the deal:

I need to perform **real-time analytics** on **data from mongoDB** collections. My analyzer must be written in an interpreted language (preferably in **Python**).

From what I read, **spark-streaming** looked like the perfect tool at first sight. But it appears impossible, at least in Python, to create an input DStream from mongoDB according to the [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#custom-sources). Is there any alternative such as passing data from mongoDB to spark using Apache Kafka? Or should I try another framework like Apache storm?

I'm a bit lost among all these technologies which are new for me. What framework(s) would you guys use to implement this analyzer?

Comment: Mongo does not seems the right tool for this. What you describe is a system that takes a streaming input from whatever application you have, stores it in a queue like kafka, and then put storm/spark on top of that to make sense of that data and *finally* store it in a db like mongo.

Comment: Mongo is not fit as a queue, not only because it is not designed that way, but also because its write consistency is bad (I have seen > 1% write failures)

Comment: @RickyA you have? In what scenario?

Comment: Any scenario, but especially on high write loads (like what you describe). Mongo is just not write consistent. That may be acceptable for your application, but just keep it in mind. Never ever store data in there that you really care about.

Comment: @RickyA hmm, fascinating I have never experienced loss on a acknowledged write regardless of load

Comment: [Lambda architecture](http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/07/questioning-the-lambda-architecture.html)

Comment: @Sammaye: not in smaller operations, but at scale it has the nasty habit of just drop writes on you in [unpredictable ways](https://aphyr.com/posts/284-call-me-maybe-mongodb). Mongo is great in the green field phase of a new application, but as soon as you start to scale things dump it as a core data store.

Comment: @RickyA I have seen and answered that article before, if I remember my answer I found the article was not only misleading but also lieing

Comment: @RickyA also he uses those articles to market his own DB tech